useEffect() with empty dependency array not running on page refresh
I am trying to do some session verification when my page is initially loaded. The AuthenticationRequiredComponent is used as a wrapper for other components that require authentication. If users are not logged in, they should be redirected to the login page. This component has a useEffect callback defined with an empty dependency array, because it subscribes to an auth state change (it is using Firebase Auth). If I go through the whole process of logging in to my website, and get to a page that uses this wrapper, the useEffect is called correctly. However, if I am in a page that uses this wrapper and I hit refresh or if I navigate directly to the url of a page that uses this wrapper, the useEffect is not being called, which results in the page not working correctly. The project is fairly large, so I cannot post the entire code. I will add pseudocode of some of the parent elements for structure:
export const AuthenticationRequiredComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const { session, dispatch } = useContext (SessionContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate ();

    const [ loadingLogin, setLoadingLogin ] = useState (false);

    /* This is the useEffect() that is not running */
    useEffect (() => {
        return isLoggedIn (setLoadingLogin, doWithUser, handleError);
    }, []);

    useEffect (() => {
        if (!session.loggedIn) {
            navigate ("/login");
        }
    }, [ session ]);

    function doWithUser ({ user, token }) {
        dispatch ({ type: "login", user, token: token });
    }

    function handleError (err) {
        console.error (err);
        dispatch ({ type: "logout" });
    }

    return children;
};

/* This is the parent component */
const MainComponent = () => {
    return <AuthenticationRequiredComponent>
        <Navbar />

        <Outlet />
    </AuthenticationRequiredComponent>
}

/* This creates a "route" object, which is then passed to an upper level array,
   and eventually a router is created through `createBrowserRouter`*/
export const businessRoute = {
    path: ":businessId",
    element: <MainComponent />,
    errorElement: <>Error</>,
    children: [
        homeRoute,
        ...
    ]
};

I read the documentation on useEffect, and it says that effects with empty dependency arrays are only run after the initial render. Why then are they not triggered when I refresh the page? When does this initial render happen? Looking around I also noticed that there are other components whose useEffect with empty dependency arrays are not being called on similar scenarios. I would appreciate any help on figuring out why this is happening.

I think you should remove the return before your isLoggedIn function. The return inside a useEffect callback is for the cleanup function that is run on dependency change  (before re-running the effect) or component unmount.

The isLoggedIn function internally does return onAuthStateChanged(...), which is a firebase defined function that returns an Unsubscribe function. I return it because it serves as part of the cleanup. I fear that not returning it might not unsibscribe some functions to events, which could result in the existence of multiple listeners. Is there any reason why you think it could be causing this?

I was lacking context about the function and jumped to conclusions, my apologies.

What makes you think that only that first useEffect hook isn't running? It's not exactly doing much, is it? Please [edit] to clarify the exact specific problem and provide a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and clearer details.

@DrewReese You are right, I apologize. I did try verifying which parts were running through console logs and breakpoints. For some reason useEffect isn't. I've been trying to recreate it on a smaller project as a minimal reproducible example, but I can't reproduce this scenario. This leads me to think that there is likely another problem causing this that is nested within my project's code. Unfortunately, I cannot upload all of it. I suppose I'll keep looking into it, and post an answer as soon as I find the issue. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate them. In any case, thanks!

The reason why useEffect with empty dependencies was not running on some components was that their children components ran into errors. These errors resulted in the parent component never calling useEffect because the app crashed before it could. These errors only happened when I refreshed the page or went directly to a route, which made things hard to pin down. In the case of AuthenticationRequiredComponent, it could be easily solved by changing the return statement so that it returns the children only if the the user is logged in (won't look too good but will work). Otherwise, the children would eventually crash the app because they require session info.
export const AuthenticationRequiredComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const { session, dispatch } = useContext (SessionContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate ();

    const [ loadingLogin, setLoadingLogin ] = useState (false);

    /* This is the useEffect() that is not running */
    useEffect (() => {
        return isLoggedIn (setLoadingLogin, doWithUser, handleError);
    }, []);

    useEffect (() => {
        if (!session.loggedIn) {
            navigate ("/login");
        }
    }, [ session ]);

    function doWithUser ({ user, token }) {
        dispatch ({ type: "login", user, token: token });
    }

    function handleError (err) {
        console.error (err);
        dispatch ({ type: "logout" });
    }

    return session.loggedIn && children;    // Modified Line
};

The problem had little to do with the hook itself or the component lifecycle, and had more to do with errors on some other parts of the code (which makes me feel kinda dumb). Still, I hope this helps in some way.
